# c++ doesn't set some of the array elements to nullptr

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Inside of `int main()` i declared `double* arr = new double[2];` (an array that its items should be set to double or to nothing)

then i tried to change the values of the array elements from another function `void func(double* arr_pointer[2])` by setting them to

```
arr_pointer[1] = nullptr;
arr_pointer[0] = nullptr;
```

but after i checked whenever their values changed to `nullptr` (in the main function) by printing out

`cout << (nullptr == &arr[0]) << ' ' << (nullptr == &arr[1])`

i got `1 0` in the console,
why?

minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>

void func(double* arr_pointer[2], double& abc) {
    if (abc > 0) {
        (*arr_pointer)[0] = 20;
        (*arr_pointer)[1] = 22;
    }
    else if (abc == 0) {
        (*arr_pointer)[0] = 10;
        arr_pointer[1] = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        arr_pointer[1] = nullptr;
        arr_pointer[0] = nullptr;
    }
}

int main() {
    double* arr = new double[2];
    double abc = -1.2;
    func(&arr, abc)
    std::cout << (nullptr == &arr[0]) << ' ' << (nullptr == &arr[1])
}
```

Comment: Can we get a [mre], this code should not compile?  `arr` is a pointer to an array of 2 doubles while `arr_pointer` is an array of two pointers to double.

Comment: `&arr[0]` is the _address_ of the first element, not the value. I dobut the address of a local variable will ever be null.

Comment: You declared a dynamic array of doubles, not an array of pointers to doubles.

Comment: I wonder if an earlier iteration of this code attempted `nullptr == arr[0]`, and an error message was misinterpreted to imply that `arr[0]` had to become a pointer somehow.

Comment: You're only one step away to win the [three-star programmer award](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) :) In the mean time, make your life easier and send `arr` rather than `&arr` to `f` and redefine `f` so it takes `double* arr_pointer` (without the `[2]`).

Comment: That will require to use a sentinel value rather than nullptr. You can have NaNs, Infinities, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> double* arr = new double[2];
> ```
>
> (an array that its items should be set to double or to nothing)

`arr` is a  pointer to a `double`. It points to the first element of an array of 2 doubles. The elements are double objects; they cannot be "nothing" objects. Furthermore, the array doesn't contain any pointers.

Sidenote: Avoid owning bare pointers. Prefer using `std::vector`.

> ```
> void func(double* arr_pointer[2])
> ```

Function parameters of array types are adjusted to be pointers to element of such array. The parameter of this function is `double**` i.e. pointer to pointer to double.

You will not be able to call `func(arr)` because a `double*` is not implicitly convertible to `double**`.

> ```
> cout << (nullptr == &arr[0]) << ' ' << (nullptr == &arr[1])
> ```

You are comparing the addresses of the array elements with null. The address of neither element should compare equal to null unless you've modified `arr` after its initialisation.

---

Regarding your edit:

> ```
> func(&arr, abc)
> ```

`arr` is a singular pointer object. It is not an element in an array of multiple pointers.

> ```
> arr_pointer[1] = nullptr;
> ```

`arr_pointer[1]` points past the end of the `arr` object, and assigning to it causes undefined behaviour. If the output of the program is something that you don't expect, it's probably because the behaviour of the program is undefined. If the program is what you *do* expect, it's probably in spite of the behaviour being undefined. Don't do this.

> ```
> arr_pointer[0] = nullptr;
> ```

Since `arr_pointer` points to `arr`, indirecting through `arr_pointer` and assigning will cause `arr` to be assigned. In other words, this will set `arr` to point to null. Since `arr` was the sole pointer to the dynamic array, this means that the allocation can no longer be deallocated; This is a memory leak.

After this assignment, it's questionable whether `&arr[0]` is allowed because that subscript operator would be indirecting through a null pointer. However if we assume it to be allowed, then it's reasonable that `arr == nullptr` implies `&arr[0] == nullptr`.

Comment: While I agree with most of what you have here, none of it answers why the code compiles and gives the output it does: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cacf3f59c863dfb

Comment: @NathanOliver It compiles fine because the program is well-formed. And the output is what it is because the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the parameter `double* arr_pointer[2]` is not an array of two pointers, it is a pointer to a pointer to `double`; it is equivalent to `double** arr_pointer`.
(You can't pass arrays to functions; the `[]` notation is only a hint to the human reader that the argument is supposed to be an array.)

Your code has undefined behaviour, so it can output anything.
Perhaps this is best explained by inlining the function:

```
int main() {
    double* arr = new double[2];
    double abc = -1.2;

    double** arr_pointer = &arr;
    // Now, *arr_pointer, a.k.a. arr_pointer[0], is the same as arr
    // and *(arr_pointer + 1), a.k.a arr_pointer[1], does not exist.
    // It is undefined to dereference arr_pointer + 1.
    
    if (abc > 0) {
        (*arr_pointer)[0] = 20; // arr[0] = 20
        (*arr_pointer)[1] = 22; // arr[1] = 20
    }
    else if (abc == 0) {
        (*arr_pointer)[0] = 10; // arr[0] = 10
        arr_pointer[1] = nullptr; // arr_pointer[1] does not exist - undefined
    }
    else {
        arr_pointer[1] = nullptr; // arr_pointer[1] does not exist - undefined
        arr_pointer[0] = nullptr; // arr = nullptr
    }
    
    std::cout << (nullptr == &arr[0]) << ' ' << (nullptr == &arr[1])
}
```